# Multi-Dimensional Array Formatting

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm working on a personal project to create a keyword generating tool.
I have setup a recursive function to loop through a multi-dimensional array to find out all possible combinations in the supplied list of keywords.

```
public function recurseful($start, $args)
{
if (is_array($args))
    {
        foreach ($args[0] as $value)
        {
            $this->output[] = trim("{$start} {$value}");
            if (count($args) > 1)
            {
                $this->recurseful($value, array_slice($args, 1));
            }
        }
    }
return;
}
```

I'm passing in:

```
$data = array(
    array('New York', 'New York City'),
    array('hotel', 'lodging','motel'),
);

$results = recurseful('', $data);
```

It successfully iterates through and gives me a list of various keyword combinations. However, it's returning them all in a single array of *$output*. The function is designed to take the values from $Data[0] (or rather $args[0]) and match them with any other keywords given.

I'd rather them returned

```
1st ('New York', 'New York City')
2nd ('New York hotel', 'New York lodging', 'New York motel')
3rd ('New York City hotel', 'New York City lodging', 'New York City motel')
```

It currently returns all of those matches into one. How would I make them go to a different array? Being that the *1st* is an exact match of the `$data[0]`, that is easy to get to, but how would I force a new array after looping through all possible combinations for one value in `$data[0]`? (So if there were 3 values in `$data[0]`, there would be 3 additional arrays returned).

**Screenshots**
A user would enter desired word choices into a spreadsheet.
[image: Initial Input]

Results would be returned similar to this. So I'd like to put each column of data into it's own array.
[image: Expected Output]
The current solution above simply puts everything into its own array, therefore would be returned back in the same column.

[image: var_dump]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that i understand what output you want, but merging arrays of $data before you pass them could help. Look for php functions [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: What output you expect there?

Comment: I'm expecting a multi-dimensional array (being assigned to $this->output. And then for them to be formatted like I outlined above.

Comment: I am not familiar with that function. Looks to be pretty powerful. I'm looking at a few examples of it, and am not entirely sure how I would use it to accomplish what I want.
I'll post a screenshot so you can see what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arrived on a working solution after much more thought & help from coworkers.

```
function permutate($data, $limit){
    $this->limit = $limit;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->numLevels = count($this->data);

    $this->possiblePermutations = 1;
    foreach ($this->data as $array){
        $this->possiblePermutations *= count($array);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numLevels - 0; $i++){
        $this->permutations[$i] = array();
    }

    $this->recurse(0, 0, '');

    return $this->permutations;
}

private function recurse($currentLevel, $level, $string){
    if ($this->numPerms == $this->limit) 
        return;

    foreach ($this->data[$level] as $val){
        if ($this->numPerms == $this->limit) 
            return;

        $newString = "$string $val";
        if ($level == $currentLevel){
            $this->permutations[$level][] = trim($newString);
            $this->numPerms++;
        }

        if ($level < $this->numLevels - 1 AND $level <= $currentLevel){
            $this->recurse($currentLevel, $level + 1, $newString);
        }
    }

    if (! $level AND $currentLevel < $this->numLevels){
        $this->recurse($currentLevel + 1, 0, '');
    }
}
```

This gives me the desired results.